# Right structure for nested while loop

Tags: python, numpy, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to fill up a 2D array with data rows selected on basis of a criterion spelled out in np.append. Python doesn't seem to complain about what I've done but somethings wrong with the nesting I guess and the loop gets stuck. I'm not sure whats wrong with it. My current thought is that somethings wrong with the way I structured the nested while loop in Python. I would appreciate if someone could point out the mistake.

```
nrows = 132
scan_length = 22
fulldata = fulldatat[0:0] # The actual data array of shape (528,32768)
ch = 0
while ch <= 3:
    n = 1
   while n <= nscans:
     fulldata = np.append(fulldata, fulldatat[ch*nrows:ch*nrows+scan_length*n],axis=0)
   n += 1
ch += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

"for" is more appropriate than "while" for this type of loop :

```
nrows = 132
scan_length = 22
fulldata = fulldatat[0:0] # The actual data array of shape (528,32768)
for ch in range(4):
   for n in range(1, nscans+1):
       fulldata = np.append(fulldata, fulldatat[ch*nrows:ch*nrows+scan_length*n],axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
nrows = 132
scan_length = 22
fulldata = fulldatat[0:0] # The actual data array of shape (528,32768)
ch = 0
while ch <= 3:
    n = 1
    while n <= nscans:
       fulldata = np.append(fulldata, fulldatat[ch*nrows:ch*nrows+scan_length*n],axis=0)
       n += 1
    ch += 1
```

[Code indentation](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html) needs to be care about.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion Aman. Im going to try that. Do you think the code itself looks fine?